# Jquery : Get variable value from ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have below code , here i need to get Value1 from .done and assign it outSideValue. How i can get it ?

```
function callGetTxt(){

 var outSideValue;
  $.ajax({
      url: 'data',
      cache: false
  })
  .done(function( text ) {

       arr1 = text.split('\n');

       var Value1 = arr1[0];


    });



}
```

Comment: outSideValue = Value1 in the .done function, I think.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: what kinds of data "text" is, why this line for "text.split('\n');"

Comment: @praveen , its reading data from a text file , where values are separated by new line

Answer (score 0):

how about this one?

```
formData = {
    outSideValue: outSideValue
}
$.ajax({
    url: "data",
    cache: false,
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        //success handling
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //error handling
    }
});
```